# How to remove spaces at the top and bottom of an HTML email?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I want to create an HTML email with tables. But my problem is that when I send the email from Gmail to an iCloud email there is a white space at the top and bottom which I don't want.

Here is an excerpt of my code that I prepared for this question.

I tried adding `style="border-collapse:` to my table and also tried adding `style="margin: 0; padding: 0;` but neither seemed to work. If I add the margin to zero, the white space in my index.html disappears when I open it from my PC, but doesn't disappear when I open the email from my iPhone.

How it looks on iCloud:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <table width="640px" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M2OgVKj.jpeg" style="display: block;
                    width: 100%" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Chrome seems to set a default 8px margin on the body of the snippet's frame.

Comment: @phuzi Chrome would yb default also apply the margins at the sides not only top and bottom. however this is an `html-email` question not a browser website question.

Comment: @tacoshy Okay, I could have made my point a little clearer. What I was trying to say is that whatever is rendering the HTML/email may be doing something similar and applying a default non-zero margin to the top and bottom of the rendered body of the email. I'm not familiar with iCloud but being an Apple thing I suspect it may use Webkit/Safari behind the scenes.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, try setting margin and padding to 0 on both `html` and `body`.

Comment: For images also add `vertical-align:top`

Answer (score -1):

Add `margin:0` on body and then try:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 
</head>

<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
  <table width="640px" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M2OgVKj.jpeg" style="display: block;
                    width: 100%" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```